# Как создать дату в определенном формате JS

Tags: javascript

new Date() возвращает дату в формате: день недели, месяц(словом), день, год, часы, минуты, секунды.
Можно ли как-то создавать сразу дату в определенном формате? ( но не используя getDay и т.п.)
Например: день, месяц, год (20 08 2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте эту библиотеку
https://momentjs.com/
Format Dates

Comment: Там методов милиард.

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать с помощью метода `toLocaleString()`

```js
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 7, 20, 10, 51, 40))

console.log(date.toLocaleString('ru-RU'))
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'))
console.log(date.toLocaleString('ko-KR'))
```

Метод настраиваемый, подробнее на [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 1):

«не используя getDay и т.п.» — нельзя)

```js
function getFormatDate(join){
  join = join || ' '; // разделитель по дефолту
  
  var d = new Date();  
  return addZero(d.getDate()) + join + addZero(d.getMonth() + 1) + join + d.getFullYear();  
}

function addZero(num){ return +num < 10 ? '0' + num : num }

console.log( getFormatDate() );
console.log( getFormatDate('.') );
console.log( getFormatDate('/') );
console.log( getFormatDate(' - ') );
```

• [Дата и Время](http://learn.javascript.ru/date)

• [Условный оператор '?'](http://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#uslovnyy-operator)